# Having issues with For loop in Python with a not key word

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I researched a lot on this, but I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong. Please help!!!

**Objective of the program:**
Keep asking a question to choose an option to the user, until the user chooses the one in the list provided.
**Issue**: I just can't get the `not` keyword working.

**Code Syntax:**

```
items = {'1': '2', '3': '4', '5': '6'}
choice = input("Select your item: ")
print(choice)
for choice not in items:
    if choice in items:
        the_choice = items[choice]
        print("You chose",the_choice)
        break
    else:
        print("Uh oh, I don't know about that item")
```

**Error from eclipse:**

```
for not choice in items:
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Error line is not in the posted code snippet.

Comment: This is really not a good question, you must find solution your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
items = {'1': '2', '3': '4', '5': '6'}

while True:
    choice = input("Select your item: ")
    print(choice)
    if choice in items:
        the_choice = items[choice]
        print("You chose",the_choice)
        break

    print("Uh oh, I don't know about that item")
```

Comment: `else` is unnecessary.

Comment: But he wants to print something if there is not match. @Austin

Comment: A `print` after an `if` that `break`s works only if `if` condition is not satisfied. So there is no need of `else:` line.

Comment: Oh! thanks. I have updated my answer. Have you said about this?

Answer (score 0):

just ignore not keyword from your code

```
items = {'1': '2', '3': '4', '5': '6'}
    choice = input("Select your item: ")
    print(choice)
    for choice  in items:
       if choice in items:
        the_choice = items[choice]
        print("You chose",the_choice)
        break
    else:
        print("Uh oh, I don't know about that item")
```

Comment: Indentation matters.

Answer (score 0):

```
items = {'1': '2', '3': '4', '5': '6'}
choice = ''

while choice not in items:
    choice = input("Select your item: ")
    print(choice)
    if choice in items:
        the_choice = items[choice]
        print("You chose",the_choice)
    else:
        print("Uh oh, I don't know about that item")
```

Answer (score 0):

The following syntax:

```
for item in collection
```

is used to iterate over all the individual `item` that are stored in `collection` (ex: a list or a dictionary).

When you write

```
for item not in collection
```

you probably mean iterate over all the items that are not in collection, which doesn't make much sense.

You can achieve what you want to do with the following:

```
items = {'1': '2', '3': '4', '5': '6'}
choice = input("Select your item: ")

while choice not in items:
    print("Uh oh, I don't know about that item")
    choice = input("Select your item: ")

the_choice = items[choice]
print("You chose",the_choice)
```

The following line

```
while choice not in items
```

checks if `choice` is present in `items` or not. If it's present, then the loop will terminate otherwise it will continue until user does not enter a `choice` that is present in `items`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see why it shouldn't work while **completely ignoring** the **syntax part**:

`items` consists of `{'1': '2', '3': '4', '5': '6'}`. The complement of `items`, say `citems` should consist of all strings excluding the ones in `items`.

`for not choice in items` is like saying `for choice in citems`. It wouldn't make sense for the interpreter since defining such a large set is really a problem here.

However, your problem can be solved by:

```
items = {'1': '2', '3': '4', '5': '6'}
choice = input("Select your item: ")

while choice not in items:
    print("Uh oh, I don't know about that item")
    choice = input("Select your item: ")

the_choice = choice #assuming you want to place the value of `choice` in `the_choice` for some reason
print("You chose",the_choice)
```